# Adding a overlay layer on an embedded vimeo player

Tags: javascript, html, css, vimeo

So Here's the video that i'm embedded to my website.
[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hgtvqatm/)

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/152985022?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="300" height="169" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The problem is, it's small and the play and other buttons button covers the half screen.

so is there any way to add a layer image on the player and when you click on the image the video should start playing.

Comment: why not make the iframe bigger?

Comment: Why use an `iframe`? Also, take a look at the [Vimeo JavaScript API](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api).

Comment: i need it to be small.

Comment: check the solution I've posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would offer you this solution :
http://jsfiddle.net/yehiaawad/hgtvqatm/2/

HTML

```
 <div id="vidFrame" class="play">
<iframe id="vimeo-video" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/152985022?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="300" height="169" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
  <img id="vimeo-id" width="300" height="169" src="" />
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
callback=?', {format: "json"}, function(data) {
        $("#vimeo-id").attr("src",data[0].thumbnail_large);
});

$("#vimeo-id").on("click",function(){
$(this).fadeOut();
var player=$f($("#vimeo-video")[0]);
 player.api("play");
})
```

CSS:

```
#vimeo-id,iframe{
  position:absolute;
}
#vimeo-id{
 cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: nice, any way to resize the play and other buttons?

Comment: @Zack https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed according to Vimeo documentation unfortunately no

Comment: btw Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971297/how-to-hide-vimeo-controls it might be useful in case if you want to hide the control bar

Answer (score 3):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grPeyq

this is what I could come up with, you can replace the button with an image,
button is disabled until video player is "ready", this requires jquery 2.1.4

```js
$(function() {
  document.getElementById("playbutton").disabled = true;
  var player = $('iframe');
  var playerOrigin = '*';
  // Listen for messages from the player
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
  }

  function onMessageReceived(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(data.event);
    if (data.event === "ready") {
      //attach ready function to the image
      document.getElementById("playbutton").disabled = false;
      
      $('#playbutton').click(function() {
        player[0].contentWindow.postMessage({
          "method": "play"
        }, playerOrigin);
        $(this).remove();
      });

    }
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<button style ="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;width: 300px;height:169px" id="playbutton">
    Play
</button>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/152985022?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&api=1" width="300" height="169" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>    
</div>
```

Comment: nice, is there a way to resize the play and other buttons?

Comment: you can remove the whole overlay adding &background=1 to the iframe parameters, you could then build your own buttons, volume etc the size that you want them (note this setting will set the video to autoloop and mute by default, however this can be added back with javascript) I recommend you checkout the vimeo javascript api