# Mute/unmute Vimeo video when Web page get loads using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, vimeo

I integrated Vimeo Video in my site and I used 'background= 1' parameter in query string to remove all the default functionalities but it cause a problem that my Video get muted when it loads and I want to unmute the video on page load.

I am beginner so please Give me some good and simple solution keeping in mind that background = 1 should stay there.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
<script>
 var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('background');

 $(document).ready(function() {
  if (dynamicContent=='1') {
    $('#vi-video-1-container').attr('data-audio-volume', 1);
    $("#vi-banner-video").vimeo("setVolume", 1);
  }
});   
</script>
```

Comment: SO is not a coding service, please show us what you have tried so far yourself

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sir I have edited the post and add what I tried so far.

Comment: Yes, i can see that but, you should really take your time and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . there is a better chance of people being able to help you if you post all relevant code.

Comment: Instead of using background mode why don't you customize the video as explained here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224972808-Customizing-the-embedded-player

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks A lot. This is quite useful!

Comment: @Farzan let me check this out!

Comment: There is no way you can hide the controls and still allow full volume. This setting can only be changed by the owner of the video: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971297/how-to-hide-vimeo-controls

Comment: Thank you but I did it using Jquery and now Volume has been set to on, on page load.