# Hiding the vimeo player's sidedock

Tags: vimeo

Is there a way to permanently hide the vimeo player's sidedock (in upper right corner)?

The vimeo player is in an IFrame and while it let's me hide all of the controls via the &controls=false url query parameter, I don't see any way to turn off just the sidedock.

Answer (score 1):

According to this  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971297/how-to-hide-vimeo-controls#24972198) , you will need a Plus or Pro account do hide the side dock.  And you can do that from `https://vimeo.com/{your_video_id}/settings/embed`.